# Current Links examples in Formatting Help Center page have spurious backticks

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, hyperlinks, help-center

There are spurious inline code backticks in the current [Links and Advanced Links](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) examples in the Help Center.

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXrzQ.png) what the first part currently looks like; same problem for the "Advanced links" section:

[image: Example shown as Markdown code block with extra backticks]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spurious backticks have been removed and locked in a closet until we need them.

Comment: -1, that's backtick cruelty